# How can I center something if I don't know ahead of time what the width is?

Tags: html, css, margin, center

I am trying to center a paragraph tag with some text in it within a div, but I can't seem to center it using margin: 0 auto without having to specify a fixed width for the paragraph. I don't want to specify a fixed width, because I will have dynamic text coming into the paragraph tag and it will always be a different width based on how much text it is.

Does anyone know how I can center the paragraph tag within the div without having to specify a fixed width for the paragraph or without using tables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to do it using a style sheet.

Style sheet:

```
div.center-content
{
    text-align: center;
}

div.center-content p
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need the second CSS rule?

Comment: Mostly habit on my part to remove the center alignment of text as soon as I don't need it any more. In this case it will have no effect.

Comment: The auto margins may help alignment in some browsers, again it's just something I do out of habit and can't remember the precise reason for.

Comment: Ah ... now, I get it. Without the rule, the "p" would inherit the "text-align: center" from the "div" around it (so the text *inside* the paragraph would be centered, too).

Comment: Yes, exactly. I forgot to switch it back enough times to do it by default now.

Answer (score 2):

Found this: [Centering Block-level Content With Unknown Width](http://www.zoffix.com/css/center#block-no-width).

Answer (score 1):

Besides "text-align" property

for centering elements inside block elements like div

use css like

```
 margin:auto
```

something like what is posted below

When vertically-centering, its better to use Tables (this in most cases is the only the cross-browser compatible solution )

you can use

```
 "text-align:center"  

 "vertical-align:middle"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is to contain the element in a block level element and do:

```
.innerElement {margin:0 auto}
```

Given they are both block level elements that don't have the float parameter, it should work great!

Answer (score 1):

here a nice workaround for [centering a div with no width](http://www.kensfi.com/how-to-align-center-a-div-with-no-width-declared/).

is tableless and is working in any browser!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using inline CSS:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Or using just HTML

```
<p align="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: Inline CSS is bad practice compared to an external stylesheet and using the align attribute is bad practice compared to using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if the div has set width all you need is

.myDiv { text-align:center; }

Also listen to garry's comment. under no circumstances use inline css.

Also another dirty fix for this in case you have other stuff in the div to centre:

you can always:

$('.youParagraph or .otherContent').wrap('');

Obviously do not practice this if you work within a large team and separation of concerns is an issue.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, auto margins need set width since by default block-level element, such as

would expand onto whole available width.

If you're not supporting IE < 8 you could just set { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }

Otherwise, if your element is surrounded by block-level elements, you could do p { display: inline-block; } p { display: inline; } html > /**/ body p { display: inline-block; } (last two rules are for IE and resetting IE fix for sane browsers) after that, apply { text-align: center; } on the container.

As someone mentioned already, see http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Horizontal-Centering for more info.

Cheers!
    Zoffix Znet