# Align a DIV tag without knowing the width

Tags: html, css, center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I center something if I don't know ahead of time what the width is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963823/how-can-i-center-something-if-i-dont-know-ahead-of-time-what-the-width-is)

I want to know how to align a div tag withought knowing a width. This is different to other questions as I would not mind using the `<center>` tag but it seems to be 'old' in the HTML groups view. Will the `<center>` tag still be working in the future?

Thanks

Comment: Please check "Related" section at the bottom right. Your question was asked numerous times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963823/how-can-i-center-something-if-i-dont-know-ahead-of-time-what-the-width-is

Comment: @Max Do you know if the center tag will work in the future though?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated, but `text-align:center;` CSS style (should) have an identical effect.

Comment: check this why not use <center> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use `width:auto` or `width:100%` than `margin:0 auto`;

However you can see the details on the link below as its almost the same question as yours!

[How can I center align a div without knowing the width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123977/how-can-i-center-align-a-div-without-knowing-the-width?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

Blocks elements are centered by setting left and right margins to auto.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

`<center>` work continue to work for the foreseeable future, so there is no technical reason not to use it, however in modern web development one should acknowledge the principle of "[separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content)" and use HTML for semantics and CSS for layout.

Comment: You can also use the shorthand `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: check this why not use center http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Comment: @sandeep: I don't understand what you want to say with that comment. The whole problem with `<center>` is that it mixed up block and text centering. That's why it was "split up" into `margin: auto` (for blocks) and `text-align: center` (for text), and using `text-align` with hacks to center blocks is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

write like this:

```
#parent {
    text-align:center;
}
.child {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline /* IE */
    *zoom:1;/* IE */
    text-align:left;
}
```

Check this

### http://jsfiddle.net/efEgq/2/

Comment: `text-align` is for aligning text (hence the name).

Comment: hey @RoToRa; who said text-align is only for aligning text. It's also align inline TAGS also for example <a>, <span> etc.

Comment: There is no bad mark-up  & not any bad css.

Comment: +1 display:inline-block;

Comment: W3C does. Centering a block and centering running text are two completely different concepts.

Comment: @Moe Sweet: What is "good" about inline-block in this context? This is unnecessarily complicated and demonstrates misunderstanding of basic CSS concepts.

Comment: -1. OP wants to align the entire DIV, not the text (and inline elements) inside of it.

Comment: @Truth; i am not aligning the text-center i align div center because OP wants DIV center with unknown width these called tricks for example check this http://jsfiddle.net/qCTj8/

Comment: I misunderstood your answer, but now that I read it, the -1 still stands. text-aligning the parent may affect other elements in the page. While it's a good solution in some cases, it's not robust and will fail on many others.

Comment: that's why i give define text-align:left in the child

Comment: @RoToRa What good about inline-block is you can align an unknown-width block level element within an unknown-width container while keeping the static flow of elements, i.e; not begin absolutely positioned. Every approach have their pros and cons.